# Creating a dict of lambdas (all lambdas are the same)

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I want to create a dictionary of lambda functions, something like this:

```
test = {"test_{}".format(i): lambda x : x + i for i in range(3)}
```

But when I try it out as follows:

```
print(test["test_0"] (0))
print(test["test_1"] (0))
print(test["test_2"] (0))
```

I get as a result:

```
2
2
2
```

Somehow all the lambdas are the same! What is going on and how do i fix it?

Comment: Try this: `test = {"test_{}".format(i): lambda x, i=i : x + i for i in range(3)}`

Comment: @Jsevillamol, just define a function that returns a lambda. `def create_lambda(i): return lambda x: x + i`. Then use it in your loop: `test = {"test_{}".format(i): create_lambda(i) for i in range(3)}`. Should get what you want.